# How to set cells background depending on previous values of updated JTable

Tags: java, swing, timer, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm populating a Jtable with yahoo quotes whose download is scheduled every 60 seconds subclassing `Timertask`. I would change background of single cells depending on new values (e.g. if new value is less than old value background color becomes green).

I've tried (with no result) to implement a `TableCellRenderer` adding a `propertychangelistener` as follows:

```
    private static class TextCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, final int r, final int c) {
            table.setRowHeight(10);
            final JTextField text = new JTextField();
            text.setOpaque(true);//disable transparence
            text.setText(value.toString());
            text.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                   JTextField l=(JTextField)evt.getSource();
                   l.setOpaque(true);
                   String property=evt.getPropertyName();
                   double d1=(Double)evt.getOldValue();//old value
                   if(property=="text"){
                       double d2=(Double)evt.getNewValue();//new value
                       //nothing happens - mantain old backround
                       if (d2==d1){
                           l.setBackground(l.getBackground());
                       }
                       //new value>old value
                       else if (d2>d1){
                           l.setBackground(Color.green);
                       }
                       //new value<old value
                       else if (d2<d1){
                           l.setBackground(Color.red);
                       } 
                       d1=d2;
                       }

                }

            });
            return text;  
        }       
}
```

I need to understand what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: the line "d1=d2" at the end is obviously wrong, it was written in previous code, i forgot to delete it.

Comment: See this [`if(property=="text")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also not a good idea to 1. Mess with the table (table.setRowHeight) from the renderer. Table passed to the method should generally be used for read-only. 2. Creating the renderer component inside the get renderer method.

Comment: silly me... it was .equals("text"). I forgot the constructor,made it and put inside the textfield instance. I tried to print property and newValue but it returns nothing. The problem is how handle the event..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to first make use of some good ol oop design. Create a simple bean like `CurrentPrevious` where you can hold the value of the current and previous values. Add those instances of `CurrentPrevious` to the table model.

```
class CurrentPrevious {
    Double current;
    Double previous;
    // getters an setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return current.toString();
    }
}
```

You only want the `current` value to be viewed in the table, so you can simply override the `toString` of the class and return the string value of `current`.

As for the rendering, you don't need a custom render. I don't see you doing anything special with it. Creating a text field as the renderer seems pointless. Any desired editing functionality should be done with the editor component. So instead of the custom renderer, just override `prepareRenderer` of the table. Something like below:

```
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
    Object value = getValueAt(row, col);
    if (value instanceof CurrentPrevious) {
        CurrentPrevious curPrev = (CurrentPrevious) value;
        Double current = curPrev.getCurrent();
        Double previous = curPrev.getPrevious();
        Color color = getColor(current, previous);
        c.setBackground(color);
    }
    return c;
}
...
private Color getColor(Double current, Double previous) {
    Color color;
    if (current.equals(previous) || current > previous) {
        color = Color.GREEN;
    } else {
        color = Color.RED;
    }
    return color;
}
```

When the value needs to be updated, just change the value of the previous to the current, and set the current to the new value.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
    CurrentPrevious curPrev = (CurrentPrevious) model.getValueAt(i, 0);
    curPrev.setPrevious(curPrev.getCurrent());
    Double newCurrent = getRandomDouble();
    curPrev.setCurrent(newCurrent);
    model.setValueAt(curPrev, i, 0);
}
```

The result would look something like:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class ChangeCellColorDemo {

    private Random random = new Random();
    private JTable table = getTable();

    public ChangeCellColorDemo() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new TimerListener());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                CurrentPrevious curPrev = (CurrentPrevious) model.getValueAt(i, 0);
                curPrev.setPrevious(curPrev.getCurrent());
                Double newCurrent = getRandomDouble();
                curPrev.setCurrent(newCurrent);
                model.setValueAt(curPrev, i, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private JTable getTable() {
        JTable table = new JTable(getTableModel()) {
            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
                Object value = getValueAt(row, col);
                if (value instanceof CurrentPrevious) {
                    CurrentPrevious curPrev = (CurrentPrevious) value;
                    Double current = curPrev.getCurrent();
                    Double previous = curPrev.getPrevious();
                    Color color = getColor(current, previous);
                    c.setBackground(color);
                }
                return c;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }
        };
        return table;
    }

    private TableModel getTableModel() {
        String[] cols = {"Value"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(cols, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Object[] row = new Object[1];
            Double current = getRandomDouble();
            Double previous = getRandomDouble();
            row[0] = new CurrentPrevious(current, previous);
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        System.out.println(model.getRowCount());
        return model;
    }

    private Color getColor(Double current, Double previous) {
        Color color;
        if (current.equals(previous) || current > previous) {
            color = Color.GREEN;
        } else {
            color = Color.RED;
        }
        return color;
    }

    private Double getRandomDouble() {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(random.nextDouble());
        bd = bd.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }

    class CurrentPrevious {

        Double current;
        Double previous;

        public CurrentPrevious() {}

        public CurrentPrevious(Double current, Double previous) {
            this.current = current;
            this.previous = previous;
        }

        public Double getCurrent() {
            return current;
        }

        public Double getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

        public void setCurrent(Double current) {
            this.current = current;
        }

        public void setPrevious(Double previous) {
            this.previous = previous;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return current.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ChangeCellColorDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works fine. I didn' t know about beans. Thanks.

Comment: Cool glad to help. "bean" is actually short for JavaBean. It's just a [plain old java object (POJO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) that follows [JavaBean conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)